# Organizing PHPUnit TestCases

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have a set of tests that need to be run using an administrative user and some that need to be run using a non-administrative user. Furthermore a non-administrative user is registered in my system by one of those tests. Therefore I thought about using this freshly registered user to be used by the other tests.

In the [PHPUnit Manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html) a way is shown in which to execute tests in a specific order

```
<phpunit bootstrap="src/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="money">
      <file>tests/FirstTest.php</file>
      <file>tests/SecondTest.php</file>
      <file>tests/ThirdTest.php</file>
      <file>tests/FourthTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Since it is annoying to maintain this list for every new testcase I wanted to specify the testcase, that registers the specific user first, followed by all other testcases in a directory

```
<phpunit bootstrap="src/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="money">
      <file>tests/RegistrationTest.php</file>
      <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Unfortunately PHPUnit seems to ignore manually specified orders once a single `<directory>` is defined in the configuration file.

Is there any way to work around this problem and run a specific test out of a directory first?

FYI I am working with PHPUnit version 4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Tests should be independent from each other, you should not use a test to setup another.

What you need is have some code for preparing the users required for each type of test and use it from setUp or setUpBeforeClass methods when required. Each test should be able to create the data required to run.

Probably the code required for creating the user will be real code, tested in some test case. That's okay. Tests can use real code to setup the environment.

Comment: I know that it is really bad practice to let some testcases depend on others, but since the registration process is quite complex and the tests I'm writing are not interacting with the PHP code itself but with the frontend, it wouldn't be efficient to create a new user for each test and delete it afterwards.

Comment: You mean the tests are functional so you're really browsing your site? I've encountered that problem also and used the approach I proposed in my answer: have some helper module that takes the Selenium browser instance or whatever you're using and do some actions (login, create new user, etc) so the real test can start after that configuration. Also if something goes bad an exception should be triggered so the test will fail with an error, not a fail.